# -webkit-box-shadow blur with QtWebKit?

Tags: c++, css, qtwebkit

Is there any way to achieve working blur for -webkit-box-shadow at the time? Reading through the comments of this [bug report](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=23291), i recognized that this is still an issue, although the bug report is marked as `RESOLVED FIXED` since version 528 (I am using version 534.6).

Answer (score 3):

I downloaded QT(windows) version 4.7.0 with newest(now) SDK 4.7.1, still -webkit-box-shadow or box-shadow tag (css33) does not work as its suppose to. instead of a 'box shadow' it displays only 'solid border'.
Other webkit apps, like chrome work as they are suppose to.
Any fix for the same?