# -webkit-box-shadow not working correctly on Qt Webkit

Tags: qt, webkit

the -webkit-box-shadow don't work on both mac and linux.It appears only one small border with no blur. I found this
[-webkit-box-shadow blur with QtWebKit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650739/webkit-box-shadow-blur-with-qtwebkit). Are there still no fix?
My Qt is 4.7.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt 4.7.x does not contain QtWebKit which has support for blur shadow. You need to wait for the next version (whatever it is).